# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r^3 sin^2\theta \frac {2}{\sqrt {4-r^2}} dr d\theta$

Tags: definite-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r^3 sin^2\theta \frac {2}{\sqrt {4-r^2}}  dr d\theta$$

Do I need to substitute something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it as
$$
\left( \int_{0}^{1} \frac{r^{3}}{\sqrt{4 - r^{2}}}dr\right)\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin^{2}\theta d\theta \right)
$$
I believe you can do the second one yourself, and the first one can be done by using the substitution $u = 4-r^{2}$:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r^{3}}{\sqrt{4-r^{2}}} dr = \int_{4}^{3} \frac{r^{2}}{\sqrt{u}} rdr = \int_{3}^{4} \frac{4-u}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{1}{2} du =  \int_{3}^{4} \frac{2}{\sqrt{u}} - \frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}du = \cdots
$$

Comment: thanks! i can do next

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Try substituting $r = 2 \cos t$ since $(2 \cos t)^2 + (2 \sin t)^2 = 4$.

After this substitution, your integral simplifies to:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r^3 \sin^2\theta \frac {2}{2 \sin t} (-2 \sin t \ dt) d\theta$$

which cancels, and then rewrite everything in terms of $t$ and $\theta$:

$$-2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r^3 \sin^2\theta dt d\theta$$
$$-2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin^2\theta \int_{0}^{1} (2 \cos t)^3  dt d\theta$$
$$-16 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin^2\theta \int_{0}^{1} \cos^3 t \  dt d\theta$$